# memory game first and second cards

Tags: javascript

I'm still new to JavaScript programming and I'm making a memory game...

I want to set the first and second, clicked cards to the firscard and secondcard variables so that I can then check if they match or flip them again if they are not...
this is my starter code so far

```js
const cards = ['fa-diamond', 'fa-diamond',
  'fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa-paper-plane-o',
  'fa-anchor', 'fa-anchor',
  'fa-bolt', 'fa-bolt',
  'fa-cube', 'fa-cube',
  ' fa-leaf', ' fa-leaf',
  'fa-bicycle', 'fa-bicycle',
  'fa-bomb', 'fa-bomb'
];

function createCard(card) {
  return `<li class="card"><i class="fa ${card}"></i></li>`;
}

const deck = document.querySelector('.deck');

function startGame() {

  const cardList = shuffle(cards).map(function(card) {
    return createCard(card);
  });

  deck.innerHTML = cardList.join('');
}
startGame();


// Shuffle function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  while (currentIndex !== 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
let firstCard, secondCard;
const clickedCards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');


function flipCard() {
  this.classList.toggle('open');
  this.classList.toggle('show');
}

clickedCards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='deck'></div>
```

I just need you to tell me how to set the first and second clicks to my variables so that I can after that check for the match..
hope my explanation is enough if not please let me know!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... I think it's fair to say that we'd like to see more of your solution, an example being whether or not the cards are generated by JavaScript or static in HTML, as an example...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: they are  generated by JavaScript i'll share more code!

Answer (score 2):

So, is this the kinda things you're after? I've not changed too much, only removed certain features that aren't essential and a few other little pieces.

#### Edit

I've actually written a somewhat complete solution, for what I'm assuming you're trying to build, I mean it's simple enough& clean enough. Obviously you'll want to make it your own.

```js
// Config sorta stuff.
let firstCard, secondCard, index = 0;
const deck = document.querySelector('.deck');
const delay = 750, completeDelay = 100;
const icons = [
  'fa-diamond', 'fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa-anchor',
  'fa-bolt', 'fa-cube', 'fa-leaf', 'fa-bicycle',
  'fa-bomb', 'fa-address-book', 'fa-grav'
];


// Rather than enter the class name twice, just make the array from some other 
// array, basically copy each item over twice.
const cards = Array.from({
  length: icons.length * 2
}, (x, i) => icons[Math.floor(i / 2)]);


// Function to shuffle the array.
const shuffle = a => {
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
  }
  return a;
};


// A simple way to create the card.
const createCard = card => `<li class="card show" id=${(new Date()).getTime() + (index++)}><i class="fa ${card}"></i></li>`;


// A simple way to hide all of the cards that are currently on display.
const hideAll = () => document.querySelectorAll('.card.show').forEach(card => card.className = 'card');


// A simple function to check that the two cards match. 
const checkMatch = () => {
  if (firstCard.innerHTML == secondCard.innerHTML) {
    firstCard.className = 'card complete'
    secondCard.className = 'card complete';
  }

  setTimeout(onComplete, completeDelay);
};


// Update the values of first card and second card.
const assignCards = card => {
  if (firstCard == null) {
    firstCard = card;
  } else if (secondCard == null && card.id != firstCard.id) {
    secondCard = card;
    checkMatch();
  } else {
    hideAll();
    card.classList.toggle('show')
    firstCard = card;
    secondCard = null;
  }
};


// A simple function that flips the card.
const flipCard = (e) => {
  e.target.closest('li').classList.toggle('show');
  assignCards(e.target.closest('li'));
};


// A simple function that's responsible for adding event listeners.
const dispatchEvents = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));
  setTimeout(hideAll, delay);
};


// A simple function to run when the game is compelte.
const onComplete = () => {
  let isCompelte = true;

  document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(card => {
    if (card.className.indexOf('complete') == -1) {
      isCompelte = false;
    }
  });

  if (isCompelte) {
    alert('Complete!');
    startGame();
  }
};


// A simple function to start the process of everything.
const startGame = () => {
  const cardList = shuffle(cards).map(card => createCard(card));
  deck.innerHTML = cardList.join('');
  dispatchEvents();
};


// Start the game. 
startGame();
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.card.show {
  background: white;
  color: #666;
}

.card.complete {
  background: white;
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
}

.card {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: red;
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.deck {
  display: block;
  max-width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 30px auto;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1.5px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="deck">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the snippet below. What it does is first check if the variable `firstCard` has a value. If it does not, set the variable to the clicked card. If it however does have a value, than it sets the value of variable `secondCard` and checks for a match. At the end of the `checkMatches` the variables both get reset to `null`.

```js
const cards = ['fa-diamond', 'fa-diamond',
  'fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa-paper-plane-o',
  'fa-anchor', 'fa-anchor',
  'fa-bolt', 'fa-bolt',
  'fa-cube', 'fa-cube',
  ' fa-leaf', ' fa-leaf',
  'fa-bicycle', 'fa-bicycle',
  'fa-bomb', 'fa-bomb'
];

function createCard(card) {
  return `<li class="card"><i class="fa ${card}"></i></li>`;
}

const deck = document.querySelector('.deck');

function startGame() {

  const cardList = shuffle(cards).map(function(card) {
    return createCard(card);
  });

  deck.innerHTML = cardList.join('');
}
startGame();


// Shuffle function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  while (currentIndex !== 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
let firstCard, secondCard;
const clickedCards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');


function flipCard() {
  // Code here to 'flip' the card open
  if (!firstCard) {
    // No cards have been clicked so assign the first card and then leave the method
    firstCard = this;
    return;
  } else if (firstCard !== this) {
    // The first card has been clicked so assign the second card and check for matches
    secondCard = this;
    checkMatches();
  } else {
    return;
  }
  
  this.classList.toggle('open');
  this.classList.toggle('show');
}

function checkMatches() {
  // This won't work I think, you might want to check for properties of the cards
  if (firstCard === secondCard) {
    // Code to check if the cards match
  }
  
  // Hide the cards again
  firstCard.classList.toggle('show');
  secondCard.classList.toggle('show');
  
  // Reset both variables to empty
  firstCard = secondCard = null;
}

clickedCards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='deck'></div>
```